# cli error running whisper locally on MacOS error

Tags: macos, openai-whisper

I'm trying to run Whisper locally via terminal and I keep getting the following errors.. I thought i had installed all the dependencies.. anyone have any ideas?

first I switch to the version of python I know should work.
`pyenv shell 3.9.9`

I run this command
`whisper test.mp3`
and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/whisper", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
             ^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/openai-whisper/20231117/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/whisper/transcribe.py", line 458, in cli
    model = load_model(model_name, device=device, download_root=model_dir)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/openai-whisper/20231117/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/whisper/__init__.py", line 133, in load_model
    checkpoint_file = _download(_MODELS[name], download_root, in_memory)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/openai-whisper/20231117/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/whisper/__init__.py", line 51, in _download
    os.makedirs(root, exist_ok=True)
  File "<frozen os>", line 225, in makedirs
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Users/caleb/.cache/whisper'
```

I followed the instructions on the whisper repo and I thought I had all the dependencies installed correctly, including pytorch, ffmpeg, etc.

2019 Intel MacBook Pro, Sonoma 14.1.2
iTerm with ZShell
PyEnv to manage python versions (3.9.9, 3.10.10, 3.11.4, 3.11.7 and 3.12.1 are available)

Thank you!

- reinstalling python and all of the dependencies, in various ways
- restarting shell

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with whisper, however I am looking at the last part of the error message, and seeing:

`Not a directory: '/Users/caleb/.cache/whisper'`.

Look at the directory `/Users/caleb/.cache/` and see if there exist a file called "`whisper`"?

If so, rename it.  Try again.

I am guessing the file "whisper" was created and now a directory by the same name can not be created and an error is being generated.

Comment: thank you!! I posted a more detailed explanation but yeah basically this.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks so much @jewettg, you led me on the right path. A similar answer was suggested by chatgpt, and I ignored it... dumb.

So `.cache` is not a folder, it was a config file with JSON of an access token in it, from May 2023, from god knows what.

I just renamed it to `.cache2`, and everything worked! Whisper generated its own `/.cache/whisper/` folders, and now I'm good to go!

Comment: Glad looking outside the box helped!  I have had many other such interactions with software, modules and my own code.